# How do I align geom_dotplot to value of the x axis instead of having them in the center of the axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several dot_plots and the problem is that the dots align to the center of the x-axis instead of the being aligned to each value of the x-axis.

I managed to fix the problem but I loose the fill and color of my dots in the process.

```r
hemodata_graph <- hemodata %>% 
  select(Days, value, Animal_type, variable) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Days, y = value, fill = Animal_type)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", binpositions = "all" , position = "dodge" , alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, fun.args = list(mult = 1), geom = "line", aes(color = Animal_type, group = Animal_type), size = 1) +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(variable ~ ., scales = "free", strip.position = "top")
```

there 2 types of Animal_type SPF and Conventional and 10+ variables over 27 non-consecutive days

Here is what the df looks like:

```r
  X Sample.ID       Date      Time Patient.ID   variable value Animal_type Days
1 1       949 2019-06-28 0.3868056       1684 WBC 10^9/l  6.48         SPF    1
2 2       950 2019-07-02 0.4958333 S1-1796-d0 WBC 10^9/l 10.49         SPF    0
3 3       951 2019-07-02 0.4993056 S2-1797 d0 WBC 10^9/l 12.15         SPF    0
4 4       952 2019-07-02 0.5013889 S3 1798 d0 WBC 10^9/l 10.67         SPF    0
5 5       953 2019-07-02 0.5041667 S4 1799 d0 WBC 10^9/l 12.23         SPF    0
6 6       954 2019-07-02 0.5062500 S5 1800 d0 WBC 10^9/l 11.28         SPF    0
```

```
    structure(list(X = 1:100, variable = structure(c(20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), .Label = c("HCT %", "HGB g/dl", 
"LYM 10^9/l", "LYM% %", "MCH pg", "MCHC g/dl", "MCV fl", "MON 10^9/l", 
"MON% %", "MPV fl", "NEU 10^9/l", "NEU% %", "PCT %", "PDWc %", 
"PDWs fl", "PLT 10^9/l", "RBC 10^12/l", "RDWc %", "RDWs fl", 
"WBC 10^9/l"), class = "factor"), value = c(6.48, 10.49, 12.15, 
10.67, 12.23, 11.28, 12.23, 26.54, 18.95, 19.31, 16.6, 21.18, 
21.86, 12.8, 13.94, 16.68, 10.8, 14.98, 13.93, 25.59, 21.59, 
22.68, 15.86, 24.11, 21.63, 11.08, 14.03, 9.54, 13.46, 13.15, 
13.46, 18.24, 18.06, 22.18, 17.32, 21.25, 21.53, 7.08, 10.6, 
7.9, 8.22, 7.83, 7.14, 9.84, 9.28, 11.35, 9.11, 11.57, 11.87, 
7, 9.09, 7.53, 8.78, 9.74, 9.64, 6.94, 10.13, 12.45, 9.09, 10.24, 
11.16, 11.31, 11.4, 13.17, 7.84, 10.7, 13.36, 9.36, 10.47, 11.16, 
14.09, 12.58, 13.34, 11.52, 13.41, 13.17, 15.83, 14.03, 15.38, 
12.92, 12.53, 14.58, 8.28, 12.69, 14.62, 16.99, 15.74, 22.37, 
9.56, 22.46, 11.01, 11.81, 14.25, 16.11, 16.89, 13.91, 16.08, 
20.76, 18.66, 13.74), Animal_type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("Conventional", "SPF"), class = "factor"), Days = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 14, 14, 14, 14)), row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Comment: It's my first question here so I might not be on point with the layout of the question.

Comment: try `factor(Days)`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but I need the x-axis to be continuous not discrete values

Comment: Yes, you have to specify the x values inside the geoms like `geom_dotplot(aes(x=factor(Days)))+
stat_summary(aes(x=Days, color = Animal_type, group = Animal_type))`

Comment: So I tried that and it does not work, it ends up looking like [this](https://imgur.com/a/3PEpSfm)

Comment: I cannot open your picture. Please provide some reproducible data using `dput(your_data)`.

Comment: I added some reproducible data in my edit

Comment: the problem with this solution is that the Days value must not be discrete.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. The idea is to add a interaction group value of Days:Animal_type for the dots.

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Days, y = value, fill = Animal_type, color = Animal_type)) +
  geom_dotplot(aes(group = interaction(Days, Animal_type)), binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", alpha = 0.2) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, fun.args = list(mult = 1), geom = "line", size = 1) +
  facet_wrap(variable ~ ., scales = "free", strip.position = "top") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Wouah that looks exactly like what I was trying to do, at least at first sight. I did not know of this function interaction